# Skype is doing funny things when I type or click, does this necessarily mean malware may be in my computer?

Tags: malware, keyloggers, skype

I'm new to the IT Security Stack Exchange! This is my question: I've Skype installed on my Windows 7 computer. In the last few months I've noticed my mouse cursor blinks (I mean it shows that cursor that appears when the computer is processing something) every time I type or click while Skype is the "focus" of my attention.

I think this could mean someone has installed a keylogger or some kind of malware on my PC. I think I could also just be paranoid about this. This happened some time after I gave out my Skype name online because somebody wanted to collaborate with me on a project.

I've ran multiple antivirus scans with Avast! free AV, scans with MalwareBytes Anti Malware, and even during Safe Mode on that computer. Not one scan has turned up any kind of malware threat detection!

Another important detail is I keep getting unsolicited contact requests on Skype as well. I don't know who they are so I decline and mark them as spam.

I wanted to ask this question here though I don't know if its much to go on. I don't know a whole lot about computer security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems strange that odd behavior only occurs when using Skype. If there was a RAT (remote administration Trojan), which can include key logging functions, your computer would be compromised across the board.

The loading/processing cursor icon might not be signalling malware at all, its strange that you would suddenly think this is a sign of a virus. If you have scanned with multiple AV engines, its unlikely there is malware affecting your computer.

You could try inspecting Skype, looking at Windows processes for any outbound connections, among other steps but it doesn't really seem necessary.

Spam is common on Skype, if you are worried you could change your Skype password. Also try completely uninstalling Skype and reinstalling (make sure it is from a trusted source). Also, handing out your Skype name does not open your computer to malware, although it could provoke spam.

If you experience any other strange behavior, then considering further action/inspection.